# What could break `jQuery(window).width` to have it give "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).width is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have been fixing an old WordPress plugin for a while. I have been asked to fix one error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).width is not a function
```

I cannot reproduce it. The code, that triggers this error:

```
    function onResize() {
        if (jQuery(window).width() <= 640) {
            jQuery('.something').addClass('mobile');
        } else {
            jQuery('.something').removeClass('mobile');
        }
    }

    onResize();
```

To my knowledge:

1. The `window` variable is always defined in a browser context.
2. If the `jQuery` variable is not defined, I should get a different error.
3. There is no `$` variable in this code.

It looks something else broke this code in a different plugin or a theme. I would like to communicate to my superiors that the code is valid and an error is in a different place, and give them an example what that error can be.

Comment: [Best practices 2022-2023](https://www.google.com/search?q=best+practice+media+query+mobile&rlz=1C1GCEB_enNL862NL863&sxsrf=APwXEddxPJTpfl31dLzHQdeIA8VOIFtkNw:1684238875162&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLqPve5vn-AhX5_7sIHX-NCIEQpwV6BAgBEBk&biw=2134&bih=1064&dpr=1.8)

Comment: I want to communicate, that the code is valid. (I have edited question a little.) And explain my superiors, that the error is somewhere else.